# node.js quickbooks api oauth2example The redirect_uri query parameter value is invalid

Tags: node.js, quickbooks-online

I am trying to develop an integration with quickbooks, I have downloaded the node.js sample code, and have tried to run the oauth2example app, 
I have filled my public and private key, and set my call back uri to local host:3000 in quickbooks dev,

when I run the app it gives me the option to connect to quickbooks, and even login, but then i get the following error

Uh oh, there’s a connection problem.
The redirect_uri query parameter value is invalid. Make sure it is listed in the Redirect URIs section on your app's keys tab and matches it exactly. Click here to learn more about the redirect_uri query parameter.

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

You are required to match the 'Redirect_uri' in your Intuit account with the uri that you are performing the request from.

For example if you are requesting from page localhost:2000/sign_in. Go to your Intuit account > Dashboard > Your project NAME > Keys & oauth > Redirect URIs > paste in localhost:2000/sign_in